# there is a common error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- methodService

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

My code as follows :

```
var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen','ngSanitize','ngCookies','ngStorage']);
  module.factory('methodService', [ '$scope', '$timeout', '$http', 
                                    '$localStorage', 'alertService', 
               function($scope, $timeout, $http, $localStorage, alertService){
}]);


  module.factory('alertService', function () {
    var data = {
      title: 'Alert',
      message: ''
    }
    return {
      getTitle: function () {
        return data.title;
      },
      setTitle: function (title) {
        data.title = title;
      },
      getMessage: function () {
        return data.message; 
      },
      setMessage: function (message) {
        data.message = message;
      },
      alert : function(){
        ons.notification.alert({
          message: data.message,
          title: data.title
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

And there is a error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- methodService

Anybody knows the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you just write it like this? `module.factory('methodService', function($scope, $timeout, $http, $localStorage, alertService) {
});`

Comment: It also has this error

Comment: Maybe it is because of `alertService`, can you post that code as well?

Comment: Factories dont have a `$scope`...

Comment: how can I use it in the factories?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't.  If you have to, something probably needs to be refactored.  Otherwise, if you absolutely must, then I guess you have to pass it as a method parameter from your controller.

Comment: ok thanks very much.Actually this method used in my controller, but many controller use it, so I want to define a factory to archive it.I think I need redesign it.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding about 2 things :

- As said in comments the $scope is a special variable that can only be injected in controllers
- The scope object injected in the controller is different for every controller. It's not the same instance of the object. Angular is build like this : you have a $rootScope. Every other $scope inherits from that $rootScope or from another $scope. It's a tree hierarchy. Thanks to the inheritance, you can retrieve data stored in a parent $scope.

My advise : don't store $scope, don't spam the $rootScope. Just store what you need in the $scope of your controller and call your factory layer properly like this :

```
$scope.myObjectToCreate = {};//object that wll be field in a form
$scope.createObject = function(){
    myService.create($scope.myObjectToCreate);
}
//or 
$scope.createObject = function(object){
     myService.create(object);
}
// but NEVER DO THIS
$scope.createObject = myService.create;
```

The last point is about the scope of the function that will change, every use of `this` in the function `myService.create` will make it crash. Because this wil refer to `$scope` instead of `myService`